# Releasing objects that may not have been created

Tags: objective-c, memory-management

In most of the tutorials I've been reading there are examples of classes with custom init methods.

For example

```
@implementation MyPerson

-(id) initWithDefaultName {
self = [super init];
if (self) {
NSString *name = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"John Doe"];
}
return self;
}
```

Now, I know that I am supposed to pair this up with

```
-(void) dealloc
{
[name release];
[super dealloc];
}
```

What I don't understand however, is why this wouldn't crash if I call `[MyPerson init]` followed by `[MyPerson release]`

EDIT: Reading the comments below, I realised the example code above wasn't quite correct. What I'm getting at is that my custom `initWithName` method allocates and initializes an object that wouldn't exist if the standard `init` method was called. So my `dealloc` method contains code to release it, but this still works even if the name object was never created?

Comment: About that edit: `name` will **not** be released in `dealloc` since you assign to a local variable, not the `name` instance variable. That statement in the init method should probably only read `name = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"John Doe"];` for your desired effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Java if you did this:

```
Foo foo = null;
int bar foo.getBar();
```

You would get an null pointer exception. In Objective-C it is perfectly ok to send messages to `nil`, it is treated as a no-op, nothing is done.

With a small caveat; methods with return types that has a size fits the ABI's default return conventions will yield a return value equal to the data-types representation of `nil`. So this will all work and yield expected return values:

```
Foo* foo = nil;
id a = [foo objectValue];    // a will be nil
BOOL b = [foo boolValue];    // b will be NO
int c = [foo intValue];      // c will be 0
float d = [foo floatValue];  // d will be 0.0f
```

This can have great benefits to your code, imagine this example:

```
if ([myString length] > 0) {
    // Do stuff here
}
```

In this way it does not matter if `myString` is an empty string, or just `nil`. Asking for the length will return `0` in both cases. Making many operations simpler to write since the `nil` value seldom has to be accounted for.

Only for return types such as structs that does not fit in a return register will you not get a defined return value:

```
Foo* foo = nil;
CGRect a = [foo rectValue];  // content of a will be undefined.
```

Comment: is this still the case, given the modification I made to the question above?

Comment: @Jack: No you have logic errors in your scope, I wrote a comment to your question on that topic.

Answer (score 5):

Instance variables have a default value of `nil`. Sending a message to `nil` has no effect.

Answer (score 1):

You can safely send release to nil. Note that you should be retaining name when you assign it in your init, though.

Comment: Name is a string literal, here. You can retain them too, but it is not really necessary (retain simply has no effect, neither has release, AFAIK). As soon as name is not a literal, it must be retained, though.

Comment: Sorry, I just re-read the code and realised it wasn't exactly what I was getting at. I've revised it.

Answer (score 1):

You can send anything to a `nil` object and it will just be fine.

That's why most of the tutorials also set every property back to `nil` in their `viewDidUnload` method.